# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty 2 u \sin u\, \exp(-su^2)\mathrm du$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

> Evaluate $\int_0^\infty 2u \sin u \,e^{-su^2} \mathrm du$.

This integral emerged while finding Laplace Transform of $\sin(\sqrt u)$

As a start, I used:

\begin{align*}
I &= 2\int_{u=0}^{\infty} \int_{v=0}^{u} \cos v~\mathrm dv\mathrm du\\
 &= \frac{1}{s} \int_{0}^\infty \cos v \, e^{-sv^2 }\mathrm dv
\end{align*}

Again here I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(We assume $\operatorname{Re}s >0$)
$$I= \int_0^\infty 2u \sin u e^{-s u^2} \,du = \operatorname{Im} \int_{-\infty}^\infty u e^{i u - s u^2}\,du = \operatorname{Im} \frac{d}{i d \alpha} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{i \alpha u - s u^2}\,du \Big|_{\alpha=1}\,.$$

Now, we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{i \alpha u - s u^2} \,du = e^{-\alpha^2/4s} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s(u-i\alpha/2 s)^2}\,du= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}e^{-\alpha^2/4s}\,. $$

As a result, we obtain
$$I = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 s^{3/2}} e^{-1/4 s}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks but how did we get the result on second line

Comment: @MaxPayne: You shift the contour from $u\in \mathbb{R}$ to $u\in i \alpha/2 + \mathbb{R}$ and convince yourself that the small arcs at $|u|\to \infty$ do not contribute. In the end, you need to know the Gaussian integral $\int \exp(-s x^2)\,dx = \sqrt{\pi/x}$.

Comment: I think you meant $\sqrt{\pi/s}$.